# Host Android OS on a server

Tags: android, ios, server, hosting

I am unable to use the right terminology to search else if this is already answered i would not have posted.

Pls comment if silly question , I will take it off. do not vote down pls. :( a rookie

I am trying to setup a server where I can host an android environment and let users test their apps. Something like a cloud ?. I wanna see if I can host various flavors of Android so that I can test from another machine. Is it possible? what to use.

May be run a few Independent simulators on a server ?

Comment: "Is it possible?" -- yes, because you have competition. Search `cloud android emulators` in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, lots of companies do things like this to run their own build server. There are also many services that allow you to do such things on their servers (i.e. circleci). Google around and you will find a lot of stuff.

Comment: Hi, actually this is what I mean , I want to create a Ubuntu Server on a VirtualBox [maybe?] and then Install an android emulator? from here i can test/deploy applications via that Emulator. Is that correct.

Comment: Also how to go about doing a IOS Emulator if the above is correct

Comment: Is this what other cloud solutions like Xamarin and Saucelabs [came across these 2 while searching] do ?

Comment: Yes, thats what these other companies do.